# i assign true to a boolean value named "ready" but when i debug i saw it takes false in onResourceReady function

Tags: java, android

when i click the button the boolean value takes false until the resources are ready from Glide so i assign a true value but it still false i got screen shot for debugging below the code and for the 2nd screen shot the last line shows that the ready got false already and can't go into if(ready)

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    ready = false;

    if(index < totalQuestions){
        AppCompatButton clickedButton = (AppCompatButton) view;

        if (clickedButton.getText().equals(Common.listQuestions.get(index).getCorrectAnswer()))
        {
            correct.start();
            clickedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
            //clickedButton.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            correctAnswer++;
            score+=10;
            stopProgress();
            stopSound();

            //*********************
            RequestListener rl = new RequestListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.e("GLIDE","GLIDE LOAD FAILED");
                    Toast.makeText(PlayGame.this, "LOADING IMAGE FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ready = true;
                    mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Object resource, Object model, Target target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    Toast.makeText(PlayGame.this, "ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ready = true;

                    return true;
                }
            };
```

i just change my code a little bit to make sure about changing the boolean variable.. but the boolean variable still got the false value..
`
  RequestListener rl = new RequestListener() {

```
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.e("GLIDE","GLIDE LOAD FAILED");
                    Toast.makeText(PlayGame.this, "LOADING IMAGE FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ready = true;
                    mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Object resource, Object model, Target target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    ready = true;
                    Log.e("GLIDE",ready+"");
                    mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    Toast.makeText(PlayGame.this, ready+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (ready) {
                        // Toast.makeText(this, ready+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                showQuestion(++index);
                            }
                        }, 3000);

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };`
```

1.[**screen shot of debugging**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AFr2.png)

2.[**2nd screen shot of debugging**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYGOo.png)

Comment: The first line of your code sets ready to false.

Comment: yes but it should be overwrited in onResourceReady

Comment: The cursor shows the value of the variable  BEFORE the line code has been evaluated. If you were to let that line of code run and then look at the variable, then it would be "true"

Comment: when i execute the code i toast the value of ready and i saw it still false it never been true i also make a function thats gonna be executed if ready is true but the function never been reached cause the ready have false value

Comment: when  the code didn't evaluate yet the cursor show a green line but after evaluating its gonna be grey

Comment: you show the toast BEFORE you do `ready = true;`

Comment: i add another screen shot you can see it @VladyslavMatviienko last line u can see that ready is false already

Comment: that is likely because your code didn;t went to the part where it sets `ready=true`, you have `if` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant post comment so I had to answer to your question

the main problem is the `RequestListener` is a Callback and wont call right after you set it to Glide , so your code will execute line by line so your code will run like:

1. at the first line `ready` is set to false

2.if statement will run and in it you have made an instance of `RequestListener`

3.after some lines you have set listener into Glide

4.and at least you have checked `if(ready) ...`

in first step `ready` is set to false and in step 4 is still false because methods in `RequestListener` will be run later than step 4 (it depends on what it is doing) so it is false at the end of your code.

Comment: thanks for a good and comprhensive answer ..but is there any solution to make the boolean change its value as soon as OnResourceReady run with the Glide

Comment: your code is ok and ready value is changing when you assign true to it. you can check it with Log its value right after line `ready = true;`

Comment: yes bro thats right  thanks your good one.. but is there any chance to know when the boolean change its value to true

Comment: it's your code , boolean value changes only by your code. if you want to take any action when your resource is ready (i mean `onResourceReady` method) , you can call a function in that method and do your action
however your question is not so clear and I don't khow what you are trying to achive.

Comment: i put my whole function inside the `OnResourceReady` but the ready stilll false. i m new here don't know how to put my code i will edit my code and u can see

Comment: it should be ok right now , please clean and rebuild your project and see anything changes

Comment: yes bro it works thnx but another problem just happen that the Glide didn't put the picture cause i make a function inside `OnResourceReady` that maybe interrupt the Glide work i m not sure exactly but thnx so much anyway